# Related name for recursive many to many relationship not working

Tags: django, django-models

## Many to many (non-recursive)

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
   parents = models.ManyToManyField(A, related_name='children')


>>> A._meta.get_all_field_names()
['children', u'id']

>>> B._meta.get_all_field_names()
[u'id', 'parents']
```

I can get the sets of children and parents of model instances with `a.children.all()` and `b.parents.all()`

## Foreign key (recursive)

```
class FK(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child')


>>> FK._meta.get_all_field_names()
['child', u'id', 'parent']
```

Any instance of `FK` will now be able to get both its parent and its child with `fk.parent` and `fk.child`

## Many to many (recursive)

```
class M2M(models.Model):
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='children')

>>> M2M._meta.get_all_field_names()
[u'id', 'parents']
```

One would expect that, like I could access `a.children` and `fk.child`, I would also be able to access `m2m.children`. This seems to not be the case.

How do I access `m2m.children`?

I'm using Django 1.6.5.

---

### For future reference

As [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536580/3694224) said, setting `symmetrical=False` solves the problem. In a [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12641) it is explained as:

> In the case of parent/child, the relationship isn't symmetrical - if A is a child of B, it doesn't follow that A is a parent of B.

With `symmetrical=False`, the reverse relation specified in the `related_name` is created just like in the foreign key case:

```
class M2M(models.Model):
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='children', symmetrical=False)

>>> M2M._meta.get_all_field_names()
[u'id', 'parents', children]


>>> parent.children.add(child)
>>> parent.children.all()  # returns QuerySet containing the child
>>> child.parents.all()    # returns QuerySet containing the parent
```

Comment: Great question post! One minor change would be that I would not include the answer in the question post, let the answers be answer posts so that people can vote on the answers. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set `symmetrical=False`. As [the documentation for ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) says:

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a ManyToManyField on itself, and as a result, it doesn’t add a person_set attribute to the Person class. Instead, the ManyToManyField is assumed to be symmetrical – that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.
>
> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with self, set symmetrical to False. This will force Django to add the descriptor for the reverse relationship, allowing ManyToManyField relationships to be non-symmetrical.