# Stop affecting other objects of Django Many to Many model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to replicate Blood Group as Model as defined in this picture.
[image: blood group relations].

In my models.py file I had my code to replicate the blood groups like this

```
class BloodGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=3
    )
    gives = models.ManyToManyField("self")
    receives = models.ManyToManyField("self")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in my admin.py file I had registered the model as follows

```
class BloodGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = BloodGroup
    list_display = ['name', 'get_gives', 'get_receives']

    def get_gives(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([item.name for item in obj.gives.all()])

    def get_receives(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([item.name for item in obj.receives.all()])

admin.site.register(BloodGroup, BloodGroupAdmin)
```

Initially I created plain BloodGroup objects without their gives and receives attribute by providing just their names alone. Thus I create an object for all 8 types. Then as I added relationships to each object I found that adding gives or receives for one object affects other objects gives and receives too, making it impossible to replicate the structure in image.

[image]

1. How do I define relationships, without affecting other objects?
2. In my admin site, I see field names as "get_gives" and "get_receives".  How would i make the admin page show field names as "gives" and "receives" but still displaying objects as strings like the image below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For first question*, probably it is better to have only one relation `gives`. `receives` can be found from [the reverse query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships). Like this:

```
class BloodGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=3
    )
    gives = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="receives", symmetrical=False)
```

Then you only need to add objects to `gives`. `receives` will be generated automatically.

*For second question*, add `short_description` attribute to function([reference to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)). Like this:

```
get_gives.short_description = 'Gives'
get_receives.short_description = 'Receives'
```

Comment: Need to set `symmetrical=False` in order for query `obj.receives.all()` to work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535218/related-name-for-recursive-many-to-many-relationship-not-working

Comment: Here blood donors and receivers have symmetry in relation (i.e. If x can donate to y implies y can receive from x and vice-versa).
But what if relation would not have been symmetrical.
How this could have been represented as Django Models ?